# API script triggered wrongly & twice

Tags: google-apps-script

I am am trying to keep a log dynamic data derived from googlefinance for which I put an API script triggered by change

```
function appendValuesToLogSheet() {
  var rangeToLog = 'alertLo!A1:D10';
  var sheetToLogTo = 'archiveLo';
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var valuesToLog = ss.getRange(rangeToLog).getValues();
  var logSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToLogTo);
  if (!logSheet) {
    logSheet = ss.insertSheet(sheetToLogTo);
    logSheet.appendRow(['Date time', 'Data']);
  }
  var rowToAppend = [new Date()].concat(
    valuesToLog.reduce(function (a, b) { return a.concat(b); })
  );
  logSheet.appendRow(rowToAppend);
}
```

however I find that the script gets triggered even when there is no change in data and when it is triggered, it triggers twice.
Im new to the world of API script so can anyone advice me what i am doing wrong
I'd appreciate any feedback
Thanks
Ansul

a [screenshot of data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOKxr.png) is here
please note that during the day the a share price could hit many lows.

Comment: What's your end objective is, you want to store the range which `GOOGLEFINANCE` is returning in other sheet whenever someone edits the sheet, right?

Comment: Basically to keep a log of any change in data triggered by googlefinance, so not necessarily editing the sheet in terms of formula

Comment: There is no trigger for `any change in data triggered by googlefinance`, you can add `Time` based trigger to save the data periodically or `onEdit` trigger whenever user edit something in sheet.

Comment: @vector cant the api script get triggered when the value changes because if i put it as a time based trigger,  i might miss the exact time that the price change happens

Comment: Unfortunately No, there is no trigger that can fire when value change through formulas, you can set Time Based trigger, and compare the last saved value with current value. But that too is capped to minimum 60 seconds. Also Google Finance function will also refresh  when there is change in sheet or user just opened the sheet...

Comment: so there is no way to log when a value changes through googlefinance? the edit option which i assume is when the data range/formulas change, which will not really happen.

Comment: what is strange is that i do get the desired triggers, only that its two at a time(when it happens) and too repetitious

Comment: @vector how could I modify the above code to compare the last saved value with current value before executing the above code on time based trigger as suggested by you.

Comment: Can't access the sheet, to see how data actually look like. [Do keep in mind that your email address can be accessed when you share your spreadsheet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/is-it-ethical-to-ask-for-a-google-sheets-file-when-answering-a-question-even-w) , you can also attach the screenshot...

Comment: @vector I had to amend my original question to include a screenshot. Thank you for your help

Comment: The question requires more focus (as per SO guidelines, please only one question per post). If you would like to make follow up questions, please post each of them as a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script based on your latest problem statement :-

> how could I modify the above code to compare the last saved value with
> current value before executing the above code on time based trigger as
> suggested by you

```
function checkChanges()
{
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const ssSource = ss.getSheetByName('sourceSheetName') 
   const ssTarget = ss.getSheetByName('TargetSheetName')
   const targetRange = ssTarget.getDataRange().getValues();
   const sourceRange = ssSource.getDataRange().getValues();
  
   const source_Head = sourceRange.shift(); // getting Head column
   const pos_sourceTicker = source_Head.indexOf('Ticker')
   const pos_SourcePrice = source_Head.indexOf('35Lo Price')
  
   const target_Head = targetRange.shift(); // getting Head column
   const pos_targetTicker = target_Head.indexOf('Ticker')
   const pos_targetPrice = target_Head.indexOf('35Lo Price') 
   
   for(var i = 0 ; i < sourceRange.length ; i++)
   {
      const checkLastSaved = targetRange.filter(r=> r[pos_targetTicker] === sourceRange[i][pos_sourceTicker])
      if(checkLastSaved.length > 0) // Checking if that ticker is not saved yet
      {
        const lastSavedValue = checkLastSaved[checkLastSaved.length -1]
        if(lastSavedValue[pos_targetPrice] !== sourceRange[i][pos_SourcePrice]) // Checking if their is change in price
        {
          ssTarget.appendRow([new Date() , sourceRange[i][0], sourceRange[i][1], sourceRange[i][2], sourceRange[i][3]])  
        }
      }
     else // If not saved, save it
     {
       ssTarget.appendRow([new Date() , sourceRange[i][0], sourceRange[i][1], sourceRange[i][2], sourceRange[i][3]]) 
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: The above logs the change the first time correctly and just once but when say the price goes even lower, it does not log the new lower price

Comment: Would you mind sharing your spreadsheet with sample data?

Comment: its available here. Hope you can open it https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1muOCqIKoZjmaEd_yLkM7B6SfEtAw580QrtRcp-5PWTw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnsulMadhvani Check your `logLo` and `alertLo`  sheet, headers in there are having whitespaces, remove them, Don't forget to add the time based trigger from your side. Script is working fine, as I last checked.

Comment: that seems to register the new 365dLo Price, but now it logs it in every minute

Comment: As I already told, you've whitespaces in your column headers, and still you didn't removed it. Also you're not passing headers in query function, that is actually making it merge the column, change your query function to this :- `=ifna(query(HoldingsLo!A:G,"select * where D=date '"&TEXT(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label B'Ticker'",1))` , also column header `365dLo Price` in `logLo`sheet still have whitespace, you need to understand that, script trying to find the column position and from that values from array, which is breaking it, If issue persist, than you've to share spreadsheet with edit

Comment: are the changed headers what you meant? I'm not sure how those white spaces under 365dLo Price randomly appear. Could it be a glitch as the file is actively computed on the cloud 24X7?I now passed on the headers through query. The problem persists. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1muOCqIKoZjmaEd_yLkM7B6SfEtAw580QrtRcp-5PWTw/edit?usp=sharing includes editing rights